fallback.FallbackExecutor : No fallback method match found
I have the following Java method:
@Bulkhead(name = "getToken", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
@TimeLimiter(name = "getToken")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "getToken", fallbackMethod = "fallbackRequestException")
public ResponseEntity<Resources> getByTokenPayload(HttpHeaders headers, String url) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        ResponseEntity<Resources> result = service.getByTokenResource(headers, url);
    }).thenApply(result -> {
        return result;
    });
}

I added fallback method like this:
private ResponseEntity<?> fallbackRequestException(HttpHeaders headers, String url, Throwable e) throws BadRequestException {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Fallback response");
  }

When I get exception I get error:
fallback.FallbackExecutor  : No fallback method match found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture class com.test.Connector.fallbackRequestException(class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,class java.lang.String,class java.lang.Throwable)
        at io.github.resilience4j.spring6.fallback.FallbackMethod.create(FallbackMethod.java:93) ~[resilience4j-spring6-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]

Do you know what should be the method for fallbackRequestException?

The method signature should match the original method signature. Yours only has Exception not the original arguments. Which is also what the exception message is telling you.

Post updated. I updated the method but still I get the same issue. Any idea why?

@PeterPenzov Shouldn't you be returning CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Resources>> in your getByTokenPayload method? And the fallback method should match both the method parameters and the return type of the original method.

The error message explains what is wrong and what method signature it expects.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture class com.test.Connector.fallbackRequestException(class org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,class java.lang.String,class java.lang.Throwable)

If you look at this it requires a method named fallbackRequestException, with a return type of CompletableFuture and with the arguments HttpHeaders, String and Throwable.
The Throwable can be either very broad like Exception or very specific NumberFormatException. When doing a fallback it will pick the most specific fallback method.
If you look at the javadoc of the FallbackMethod class in the Resillience4J library this is explained as well.
So you will need to add a method with that name, arguments and return type.
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> fallbackRequestException(HttpHeaders headers, String str, Exception ex) {
 // Your implementation here.
}

NOTE: Given that and looking at the code of your getByTokenPayload method you either made an error in copying or it is plain wrong. As you are actually returning a CompletableFuture from the method not a ResponseEntity.
@Bulkhead(name = "getToken", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
@TimeLimiter(name = "getToken")
@CircuitBreaker(name = "getToken", fallbackMethod = "fallbackRequestException")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Resources>> getByTokenPayload(HttpHeaders headers, String url) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        ResponseEntity<Resources> result = service.getByTokenResource(headers, url);
    }).thenApply(result -> {
        return result;
    });
}



You must have the same signature of the fallbackup method  as the primary method.

Since you are using the @TimeLimiter annotation you must return a CompletableFuture in your methods.

In the fallbackup method, the response entity must contain an instance of the Resources object, not a string.


In the end, you should have code similar to this.
@Override
@TimeLimiter(name = "getToken")
@Bulkhead(name = "getToken", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
@CircuitBreaker(name = "getToken", fallbackMethod = "fallbackRequestException")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Resources>> getByTokenPayload(HttpHeaders headers, String url) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getByTokenPayload(headers, url));
}

private CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Resources>> fallbackRequestException(Throwable throwable) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok(new Resources()));
}


One more question. Into your code how I can return HttpStatus.SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE?

@PeterPenzov CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).body(new Resources())); But then the point of the fallbackup method is lost.

I just want to return message that the service is not available when for example Feign can't connect to a remote service.

@PeterPenzov Then you don't need a fallback method, just catch the exception where the CompletableFuture result is expected and send HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE to the client.
